# Let B = [1/sr2 , - 1/sr2] (next row of matrix) [1/sr2 , 1/sr2]. Find, with justification, B^1903

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am not sure how to go about this question, or how to even begin with it.  Multiplying matrices is still a bit new to me, so I find this hard to understand.  If anybody would be willing to help point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: What is $1/sr2$? Is it $\frac{1}{s} \cdot r \cdot 2$? Or $\frac{1}{s} r^2$? Or $\frac{1}{sr^2}$? This is where using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) really helps.

Comment: You can write matrices like `$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{sr^2} & -\frac{1}{sr^2} \\ \frac{1}{sr^2} & \frac{1}{sr^2}\end{bmatrix}$` in order to display $\begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{sr^2} & -\frac{1}{sr^2} \\ \frac{1}{sr^2} & \frac{1}{sr^2}\end{bmatrix}$, that way you don't have to do something embarrassing like saying "next row of matrix"

Comment: _Hint:_ If $B$ is diagonalizable ($ B  = P^{-1}D P$ for some $P$ and diagonal $D$ ) ,  then $B^n  =  P^{-1}D^n P $